# How to make a set of jbuttons invisible in java

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jbutton

Apart from using `button.setVisible(false)`, is there an easy way to set a set of `jButtons` to invisible and visible again?

The algorithm is as follows - when the user clicks the checkout button, a set of payment buttons(denomination buttons are displayed). Trying to research if there is an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: How are they defined?  In an array? List? or just on a container?

Comment: Hi - They are just on the jpanel, not sure if that is what you meant by container. New to java, still have a lot to learn

Comment: Why do you need an alternative to `button.setVisible(..)`?

Comment: The algorithm is as follows - when the user clicks the checkout button, a set of payment buttons(denomination buttons are displayed.

Comment: I think what MadProgrammer is asking is, are you defining a separate variable for each `JButton` or are they in an array? Or a List?

Comment: Hide the `JPanel` containing all of the `JButton`s, assuming that's all that it includes.

Comment: Yes I'm defining a separate variable for each 'JButton'. Unfortunately there are other elements on the jpanel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better solution is to have your buttons in an array or `List`, but if you can't do that, you can walk the immediate container (`JPanel`) looking for all the components that are instances of `JButton`

```
for (Component child : getComponents){
    if (child instanceof JButton) {
        ((JButton)child).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

This is a little heavy handed so be careful

Answer (score 2):

Put all your UI components (`JButton`) in a collection, and create a utility method that iterates over them and set the visible state.